# Matlab: sum for two time series dataset?

Tags: matlab, join, matrix, time-series

I like to sum up the observations of two time series datasets when both of them have observations based on YEAR and DOY. I also like to skip the sum when either dataset has 0 and only do the sum for the maximum observation in that DOY.

Here is the example: data_1 and data_2.

#### data_1

```
% YEAR  DOY  OBS_1

1994    109 0.42
1994    110 0.73    
1994    111 0.69    
1994    113 0.8    
1994    114 0.43    
1994    115 0.75    
1994    123 0.6    
1994    127 0.2    
1994    131 0.44    
1994    131 0.43    
1994    131 0.63    
1994    132 0.99    
1994    132 0.51    
1994    133 0.71    
1994    133 0.99    
1994    134 0.65    
1994    134 0.69    
1994    134 0.97    
1994    134 0.03    
1994    134 0    
1994    134 0    
1994    135 0.68    
1994    135 0.72    
1994    136 1.22    
1994    136 0    
1994    136 0    
1994    136 1.28    
1994    136 1.34
```

#### data_2:

```
% YEAR  DOY  OBS_2    
1994    110 0.92    
1994    111 0.34    
1994    113 0.42    
1994    114 0.37    
1994    115 0.38    
1994    122 0.22    
1994    127 0.32    
1994    131 0.34   
1994    131 0.2    
1994    132 0.51    
1994    132 0.43
1994    132 0.4    
1994    133 0.4    
1994    134 0.32    
1994    134 0.39    
1994    135 0.35    
1994    135 0.38    
1994    135 0.34    
1994    135 1.83    
1994    135 0.22    
1994    135 0.36    
1994    135 0.39    
1994    135 0.24    
1994    135 0.39    
1994    136 0.42    
1994    136 0.29    
1994    136 0.3    
1994    136 0.4    
1994    136 0.54    
1994    136 0.4
```

Comment: Please edit: select the code and format it using the code format icon

Comment: What do you mean with "when either dataset has 0"?

Comment: I see that you have repeating DOY values in both data sets. Do you want to sum all of them, or what? Please clarify, and give an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a first attempt:

```
%# maximum day of year
sz = max(max(data_1(:,2)),max(data_2(:,2)));
doy = (1:sz)';

%# get max value for each DOY in each dataset
v1 = accumarray(data_1(:,2), data_1(:,3), [sz 1], @max);
v2 = accumarray(data_2(:,2), data_2(:,3), [sz 1], @max);

%# compute the sum
v = v1 + v2;

%# keep entries where none of the values were zeros
idx = (v1~=0 & v2~=0);
v = [doy(idx(:)) v(idx(:))];
```

The result:

```
>> v
v =
          110         1.65
          111         1.03
          113         1.22
          114          0.8
          115         1.13
          127         0.52
          131         0.97
          132          1.5
          133         1.39
          134         1.36
          135         2.55
          136         1.88
```

I didn't take the `year` field into account, since its `1994` across all your data...

Comment: Hi Amro, how to tai the year field into account, because the real datasets come with many years of observations. You are truly make my life easier. Thanks.